# Pointer exercise in C

Tags: c, pointers, reference

I am currently preparing for an exam, and refreshing my pointer knowledge.

I am looking at this small exercise:

Consider the follow fragments of C programs. For each program, fill in the empty underlined spots such that the final value of the variable x is 0.

```
int x;
int *p;
p = &_____;
*p = _____;
```

I assume that the first underline is p = &x. I am little confused about the second one though.
What is the difference between p = and *p = in this situation, given that we already have int *p?

Comment: `p = ` assigns the pointer variable `p`. `*p = ` assigns a value to the address pointed to by `p`. Since `*p` is an `int` you would want an `int` for the blank after `*p =`. HINT: where else do you have an `int` in that code fragment?

Comment: `p=` assigns an address value to the pointer variable `p`. `*p=` dereferences `p` and assigns an `int` value to that address which happens to be the address of `x`. There could be any integer value on the right side. But the requirement is that `x` shall hold `0` at the end. That's limiting the options greatly

Comment: `*p = 42;` is using **indirection** through the pointer, and is the same as `x = 42;` if you have set `p = &x;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *p;
```

... declares `p` as a variable of type `int *` (a pointer to `int`).  Given that this code overall can be valid only if it appears inside a function, that declaration does not assign a value to `p`. As a result, the expression `*p` is not (yet) meaningful immediately after that declaration, despite being syntactically correct.

The subsequent

```
p =
```

assigns a value to (pointer) `p`.  Your idea of `p = &x;` seems plausible.  But this is about the value of pointer `p` itself, not about the value of the object to which `p` points.

Once `p` actually points to an object courtesy of the assignment to it, the value of the object to which it points can be accessed via `*p`, and in particular, a value can be assigned to the pointed-to object via `*p = <value here>;`.

Perhaps the thing tripping you up is that in no case is the `*` part of the name of the pointer.  In the declaration on line 2, it is part of the type (`int *`) declared for variable `p`.  In the assignment on line 4, it is a unary operator applied to variable `p`.

Comment: `Perhaps the thing tripping you up is that in no case is the * part of the name of the pointer.` -- Which is why I put it with the type declaration, as in `int* p`, despite it not being fashionable to do so.